# MySQL Syntax Issue with CONCAT AND LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure to capture an id. It concat's the last name with first name as 
"William, John" and compares with the _fullname passed which when i var_dump gives

String(13) Willam, John

Hence it should give an id.

```
IF NOT ISNULL(_fullname) THEN
            SET _fullname       = TRIM(_fullname);
            SET clause = CONCAT( clause , ' AND CONCAT(c.lname, ', ', c.fname) LIKE CONCAT('%',_fullname,'%')');
```

When i try the same query in MySQL it works perfectly fine. I'm sure that the problem is syntax in stored procedure. Can you check.

Comment: I would think the quotes around the `%`'s would need to be escaped?(`'a'%'b'` results in NULL here).

Comment: Do you mean, 

`LIKE CONCAT(%,_fullname,%)`

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Escaped, not removed..... `CONCAT(\'%\',',_fullname,',\'%\')');`, exactly like the syntax highlighting in your question hints... But, as your set the thing directly in there rather then a placeholder, `LIKE \'%',_fullname,'%\'` seems more apt/shorter. Also, look at your first concat, those are unescaped quotes too...